# Error in R: File size and implied file size differ, consider trying repair=TRUE

Tags: r, list, skip

I have a huge number of `.shps` which are characterised by serial numbers (eg. shp1,shp2,..). I want to read them in R but some of them are empty and thus I get the error

```
"Error in read.shape(filen = fn, verbose = verbose, repair = repair) : 
 File size and implied file size differ, consider trying repair=TRUE"
```

My question is how to skip those empty .shps and continue reading my files with the use of a loop?I think the `trycatch` is the answer but I have never use it. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

```
mylist=list()
for (i in 1:5000){
  mylist[[i]]=readShapeSpatial(paste0("inhere/shp",i,".shp"))
}
```

Comment: Wrap your expression with `try`: `try(readShapeSpatial(paste0("inhere/shp",i,".shp")))`.

Comment: Hi @nicola. I have tried this and I get the error: Error in read.shape(filen = fn, verbose = verbose, repair = repair) : 
  File size and implied file size differ, consider trying repair=TRUE
Error in try:try(readShapeSpatial(paste0("fls/vecvis_pt", i, "/vecvis_pt",  : 
  NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: That's exactly the point of `try`: you still are getting the errors, but the loop execution doesn't stop.

Comment: if the shp files are really "empty" (in the sense that they have 0 bytes), you can also try subsetting the files before reading them in using `file.size()`. Otherwise, the `try` should be the most workable solution :)